# Python 'requests' GET in loop eventually throws [WinError 10048]

Tags: python, python-requests

Disclaimer: This is similar to some other questions relating to this error but my program is not using any multi-threading/processing and I'm working with the 'requests' module instead of raw socket commands so none of the solutions I saw related to my issue.

I have a basic status-checking program running Python 3.4 on Windows that uses a GET request to pull some data off a status site hosted by a number of servers I have to keep watch over. The core code is setup like this:

```
import requests
import time

URL_LIST = [some, list, of, the, status, sites]    # https:// sites
session = requests.session()

previous_data = ""
while 1:
    data = ""
    for url in URL_LIST:
        headers = {'X-Auth-Token': Associated_Auth_Token}
        try:
            status = session.get(url, headers=headers).json()['status']
        except ConnectionError:
            status = "SERVER DOWN"
        data += "%s \t%s\n" % (url, status)
    if data != previous_data:
        print(data)
        previous_data = data
    time.sleep(15)
```

...which typically runs just fine for hours (this script is intended to run 24/7 and has additional logging built in I left out here for simplicity and relevance) but eventually it crashes and throws the error mentioned in the title:

```
[WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

The servers I'm requesting from are notoriously slow at times (and sometimes go down entirely, hence the try/except) so my inclination would be that after looping this over and over eventually a request has not fully finished before the next request comes through and Windows tries to step on itself, but I don't see how that could happen with my code since it iterates serially through the URLs.

Also, if this is a TIME_WAIT issue as some other related posts ran into, I'd rather not have to wait for that to finish since I'd like to update every 15 seconds or better, so then I considered closing and opening a new requests session every so often since it typically works fine for hours before hitting a snag, but based off Lukasa's comment [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3031):

> To avoid getting sockets in TIME_WAIT, the best thing to do is to use a single Session object at as high a scope as you can and leave it open for the lifetime of your program. Requests will do its best to re-use the sockets as much as possible, which should prevent them lapsing into TIME_WAIT

...it sounds that is not a good idea - though when he says 'lifetime of your program' he may not intend the statement to include 24/7 use as in my case.

So instead of blindly trying things and waiting some number of hours for the program to crash again so I can see if the error changes, I wanted to consult the wealth of knowledge here first to see if anyone can see what's going wrong and knows how I should fix it.

Thanks!